# How to assign Axios globally in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I assign Axios globally in Vue js?

I am trying to load Axios so that I can access it in any component.

I am trying as follows:

**main.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

**home.js**

```
buyers(data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        this.$axios.get(`/buyers?${data}`)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error.response.data)
            })
    })
}
```

> index.vue?6ced:203 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property '$axios' of undefined

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you've used a normal `function` for your `then` callback. Entering a new function changes the value of `this`, so it won't refer to your component. If you use an arrow function instead it should be fine. You'd need to post the surrounding code if you need further help. Note that the error message says that it can't read *'`$axios` of undefined'*. It does not say that `$axios` is undefined.

Comment: @skirtle. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
buyers(data) {
  return this.$axios.get(`/buyers?${data}`)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error.response.data
    })
  })
}
```

Generally if you find yourself creating a new Promise using the constructor you're probably doing something wrong. That should only be required when wrapping other code that doesn't use Promises.

The reason for the error you were seeing is that the extra function changes the value of `this`. Every time you enter a new function the value of `this` changes.

You could also fix it by changing this line:

```js
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

to this:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Using an arrow function would preserve the surrounding `this` value, so that it still refers to the component.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
install(vue, opts) {
      vue.prototype.$axios = $axios;
    }
```

Then `Vue.use($axios)` if you want globally

Comment: not sure why you say that, see here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html .   
The router object for example is not a component